# Errors: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: database, vb.net, validation

Here are the codes I've been making but there is a error keeps popping out. I know that it already been answered but it's not what I've been looking for.Its like a validation if the TxtIDNumber is already existed.`enter code here`Hope someone could help me...Have a nice day! :)

Codes:

```
Private Sub TxtIDNumber_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtIDNum.TextChanged
    If TxtIDNum.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString Then
        MsgBox("The ID Number you input has already existed!Try again...")
        TxtIDNum.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

And here are the error:
errors:
ArgumentOutofRangeException was unhandled

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on there being at least one 'Selected' cell in the DataGridView by referencing SelectedCells(0).

0 being the Index the exception is referring to.

If there are no cells selected, the SelectedCells collection will have a size of -1, and this exception will be thrown.

To check (the first cell of) all rows in the DataGridView, whether selected or not would require something like the following;

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Contains(TxtIDNum.Text) Then
        MsgBox("The ID Number you entered already exists! Try again...")
        TxtIDNum.Clear()
        Exit For     
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Hi! I tried the code you gave me but It got error again..The ROW in:            
If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Contains(TxtIDNum.Text).                             It says that 'row' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection.

Comment: row is declared as a DataGridViewRow in the For Each line above. I've put the code above in a sample project and it is working. I moved the code into the Leave event of the textbox so it only executes once when the textbox loses focus, rather than every time it is changed (every key press).

Comment: I use DataGridView1, should i use it? So, should i moved the code and where? Thank you for the help but I think the problem here is i can't connect the two forms, ex. form1 and form2. they should be connected that if I change something in the form2, it also changes in the form1 and reversed.

Comment: The code above uses DataGridView1 as the name of the DataGridView Control. DataGridViewRow is a type within the DataGridView. The above will solve your ArgumentOutOfRange Exception. You may need to ask another question regarding connecting the forms. Basically you either need to declare the DataGridView Control as public if you're adding it via code, or set its Modifiers property to Public in the designer. Then you can access it from form2 by using form1.DataGridView1 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the responce, it really helps me but I stop doing that code tho..Too much for my brain hahaha...I'll keep this as a guide for future.Thanks :)